# C Program compiled with GTK+3.0 fails with warning when run

Tags: c, osx-mavericks, gtk3

I've read several guides on how to use GTK+ for a GUI in C programs and I came across [this tutorial](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK+/OSX/Building) for getting GTK+ on my system. Here's everything I ran, line by line:

```
chmod +x gtk-osx-build-setup.sh
./gtk-osx-build-setup.sh
cd ~/.local/bin
./jhbuild build python
./jhbuild bootstrap
./jhbuild build meta-gtk-osx-bootstrap
./jhbuild build meta-gtk-osx-core
```

At this point, I had not discovered the `pkg-config` tick hack for compiling C programs with GTK headers, so when I ran `gcc main.c -o main` I simply got the error `main.c:1:10: fatal error: 'gtk/gtk.h' file not found`, but I had found [another tutorial](https://developer.gnome.org/jhbuild/stable/getting-started.html.en) (Command-F "jhbuild build gtk+") that suggested I do this, so I ran:

```
./jhbuild build gtk+
```

After that, I finally found other sources that suggested to run the following commands to check if my system could find the packages, so when I run `pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --cflags` I get:

```
-D_REENTRANT -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0 -I/opt/local/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/opt/local/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/dbus-1.0 -I/opt/local/lib/dbus-1.0/include -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0 -I/opt/local/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include/cairo -I/opt/local/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/harfbuzz -I/opt/local/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/atk-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/cairo -I/opt/local/include/pixman-1 -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/local/include/libpng16 -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/libpng16 -I/opt/local/include/glib-2.0 -I/opt/local/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/opt/local/include
```

And when I run `pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --libs` I get:

```
-L/opt/local/lib -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lm -lfontconfig -lfreetype -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

My `main.c` contains the following code from [this tutorial](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html#id-1.2.3.3):

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GtkWidget *window;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Window");

    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show(window);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

When I run `` gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror `pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --cflags` main.c -o main `pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --libs` ``, `main` is created with no warnings or anything, but when I run `./main` I get this warning, and the program ends instantly:

```
(main:93199): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

My computer is a Mid 2012 MacBook Pro running OS X 10.9.5 with a 2.9 GHz Intel Core i7 processor (I really have no idea how much of that information is necessary for this). I just want to resolve this warning so I can get a simple window to display without any problems.

**UPDATE:** I noticed that I installed gtk+ instead of gtk+-3.0, so I ran `~/.local/bin/jhbuild build gtk+-3.0` to install it. When I run `~/.local/bin/jhbuild info gtk+-3.0`, I get:

```
Name: gtk+-3.0
Module Set: gtk-osx
Type: autogen
Install version: 3.14.5-b4ea7a7455981175cb26a7a1a49b765e
Install date: 2015-01-27 23:49:55
URL: http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gtk+/3.14/gtk+-3.14.5.tar.xz
Version: 3.14.5
Tree-ID: 3.14.5-b4ea7a7455981175cb26a7a1a49b765e
Sourcedir: ~/gtk/source/gtk+-3.14.5
Requires: glib, pango, atk, gdk-pixbuf, gobject-introspection
Required by: meta-gtk-osx-gtk3, goocanvas2, gtkmm3
After: meta-gtk-osx-bootstrap
Before: gtk-mac-integration
```

I still get the same error, however, even after re-compiling the C program.

Comment: You need to have an X server running to run this program.

Comment: Can you elaborate? This is the first I'm hearing of any reference to an X server. Perhaps a link demonstrating proof of this requirement, or something...

Comment: Start [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System), continue [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK%2B), then [here](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/). I'm voting to close this question as too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's absolutely not true that you need an X server to run GTK programs on OSX. When you install it through gtk-osx-build, as you have done, it uses the Quartz backend, which allows it to run natively on OSX.

However, your `pkg-config` output shows that you are picking up a different copy of GTK installed in `/opt/local`, most likely from MacPorts. The default installation location for gtk-osx-build is `~/gtk/inst` which I assume you have not changed. That other copy may not have been built with the Quartz backend.

Remember that you need to compile and run your program inside `jhbuild shell`, at least until you have bundled it into an application. Otherwise the compiler won't find the executables and libraries in `~/gtk/inst`.

I also recommend uninstalling the other copy of GTK from `/opt/local` if you can, to avoid problems like this in the future.

Comment: Awesome! Now it looks like a native window and I can uninstall XQuartz!

Answer (score 0):

As n.m. suggested, I tried [installing XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/) and it works perfectly now.